# C# Is it possible to get information from file - who create file?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have file "screenshot" / **JPEG** and I'm curious which information can be stored by default in picture, which was screenshoted and if so how to get them via **C#**.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details.  Maybe some better sentence structure as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using  `System.IOFileInfo` class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

This class will provide you with some more information about the file.

e.g.

```
System.IO.FileInfo info = new FileInfo("Path to file");
```

This object will provide you with some useful information about the file that you point it to.

Comment: also try to add a code, because maybe the link will deleted later

Comment: Good point Mike, I've added an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var User= System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(FilePath).GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(path).GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your code!